# gmaps4rails not showing in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

All is in the title

I've tried:

- config.serve_static_assets = true
- I updated the gem and then: `rails generate gmaps4rails:install`

The map is perfectly showing in local mode but doesnt appear un production!
the  is totaly empty...
Here is the content of my head:

```
  <head>
  <link href="/images/favicon.ico" rel="SHORTCUT ICON">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/stylesheets/gmaps4rails.css?1314057878">
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/stylesheets/reset.css?1314057878">
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/stylesheets/default.css?1314057878">
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/stylesheets/buttons.css?1314057878">
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/stylesheets/colorbox.css?1314057878">
 <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/application.js?1314057878"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery.1.4.4.js?1314057878"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery-ui.js?1314057878"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery.colorbox-min.js?1314057878"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery-ujs-1.4.4.js?1314057878"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/application.js?1314057878"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/active_scaffold/default/active_scaffold.js?1314057900"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/active_scaffold/default/jquery.editinplace.js?1314057900"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/active_scaffold/default/date_picker_bridge.js?1314057900"></script>
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/stylesheets/active_scaffold/default/stylesheet.css?1314057900">
 <!--[if IE]><link href="/stylesheets/active_scaffold/default/stylesheet-ie.css?1314057900" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><![endif]--> 
 <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param">
 <meta content="/MYbif2q6UmcrXyAS7WyYtOViwkr8pyXjXQTTNYtQsc=" name="csrf-token">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/fr_ALL/mapfiles/api-3/6/0a/%7Bmain,places%7D.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/fr_ALL/mapfiles/api-3/6/0a/%7Bcommon,util%7D.js"></script></head>
```

Any idea?

Comment: weird, the js files don't appear in your `head`... Note that you don't need to set config_asset to true if you run the generator and include the files manually.

Comment: OK I was thinking that the gem was using <%= yield :scripts %> to include them... it was but only in local mode and don't know why doesnt in production mode with set config_asset to true.  I included it manually ant it's working now

Comment: it does include all files automatically when you include `yield :scripts`: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/app/views/gmaps4rails/_gmaps4rails.html.erb

Comment: Did you copy the js files in your /public folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with the pre 1.x, although it was fixed by calling each file individually in the manifest file after manually loading them into the vendor asset dir.

However, the latest gem worked as it said in the readme. From an older version update it via bundler, remove any of it's js files copied into the assets dir (like I had previously), run the install script again, and in the manifest file (I'm using vendor/assets/javascript/external.js) use the namespaced require statement for the files you need.

```
//= require gmaps4rails/googlemaps.js
```